# Copy Paste to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been using Excel for the longest time but would now need to use Google sheet for the new company that I work for. Seems like it is harder than I expected.

I am creating a form to track how long an employee finishes a certain task for a client.

A simple form that I created where I hide the details on Form!F1:J1 (F1 - Time now, G1 - Name of employee, H1 - Client name, I1 - task done and J1 - Start/End the task

I just want to copy and paste the values to the next empty row on the Tracker sheet.

I tried to search previous answers but doesn't seem to work. I always get an error message:

> "ReferenceError: database is not defined"

on the `var copyToSheet = database.getSheetByName('Tracker!A1');` part. Here's what I got.

```js
function Done() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var source = ss.getSheetByName('Form');
  var dataToCopy = source.getRange('F1:J1');
  var copyToSheet = database.getSheetByName('Tracker!A1');

  var sourceValues = dataToCopy.getValues();
  var lastRow = copyToSheet.getLastRow();
  copyToSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length).setValues(sourceValues);
  dataToCopy.clear({
    contentsOnly: true
  });
}
```

Comment: So... Where's the `database` defined?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the correct code somewhere and just changed it a bit.

> function Done() {
> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
> var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
> var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tracker");

> var source = copySheet.getRange(1,6,1,5); //from which row number, from which column number, 1, how many cells to copy
> var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,5);
> source.copyTo(destination,{contentsOnly:true});

//this is to delete what you input on the form after it copies and pastes to the tracker

> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form");
> var cell = ss.getRange("C4:C7");
> cell.clearContent();

> };

Comment: You should not just post solutions, you need to provide an explanation.

Comment: Don't know how to explain it either. Just combined the codes from somewhere, changed the ranges and it worked.